# Classic button javascript break if condition

Tags: javascript, salesforce-classic

Javascript is throwing an exception if I attempt to use a break; statement inside an if else.
so I'm using this code in Salesforce Classic Button Javascript

I have multiple if/else conditions.

```
if (condition1...) {
    //do stuffs
else {
    //show message 1
}

if (condition2...) {
    //do stuffs
else {
    //show message 2
}
```

How do I overcome this? I tried to use `break` or `return` I get the unexpected exception.

PROBLEM:
I'm getting both messages from condition 1 and condition 2

Answer (score 0):

So first, as a best practice try to avoid multiple `return` statement and `break` keyword, it makes the code more difficult to understand and is error prone.

Secondly if I understand, when `message 1` is shown, you don't want to show `message 2`. Depending on how `stuff 1` and `stuff 2` needs to be executed you can use one of the two approach:

**First**

`stuff 2` can be done only if `stuff 1` is also done

```js
if (condition1) {
  // do stuff 1

  if (condition2) {
    // do stuff 2
  } else {
    // show message 2
  }
} else {
  // show message 1
}
```

**Second**

`stuff 2` can be done whether or not `stuff 1` is also done

```js
let displayMessage = false

if (condition1) {
  // do stuff 1
} else {
  displayMessage = true
  // show message 1
}

if (condition2) {
    // do stuff 2
} else if (!displayMessage) {
    // show message 2
}
```